# django-allauth - Send email verification using Gmail account

Tags: django, email, gmail, django-allauth, email-verification

I have setup allauth to send out an email for every new registered user so that their email can be verified. Right now I use the email_backend so that the email is sent to the terminal instead, and everything works fine.

But now I want to can set it all up so that an email is sent, and since I will (likely) not have a local email server at the host server, but instead use for example an gmail account to send the verification email. Is this at all possible?

Comment: use mailgun, it is a better choice!

Comment: Does that mean we don't need any API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can set your gmail account to send emails. Just set these settings for django:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'gmail password'
```