# Sending email to gmail from local machine using django allauth app

Tags: django, email, django-allauth

I am trying to send a real email from my local to gmail using django allauth app.I can see the verification email through the console.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Please Confirm Your E-mail Address
From: myemail@gmail.com
To: useremail@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 15:23:19 -0000
Message-ID: <20170808152319.1056.31735@Lenovo-PC>
```

From and to email are real gmail account. I was going through [django-allauth - Send email verification using Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743396/django-allauth-send-email-verification-using-gmail-account/31743482) and settings.py contains the settings for gmail.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

But for some reason I am not getting the emails in my gmail account.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You have turned on DEBUG=TRUE and you have use

> if DEBUG:
>       EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

so, when you are in debug then allauth will send mail in the console. Remove above line then you are fine.
Check console.